# How to use Selenium with "chart.js"

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, chart.js

I've been asked to use Selenium to write some tests for a website. Several of the pages have graphs on them that are generated by the "chart.js" library. The tests require me to:

- Read the size of some of the data values in the chart
- Click on certain bars on the chart.
- Hover over certain bars and validate the tool tips

The trouble is the chart is implemented as a single HTML `canvas` element, so there is no DOM for the details of the chart that selenium can manipulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to access the chart directly using Selenium because there is no DOM, as you noted. There may be a way to access chart data using JavascriptExecutor to run JS commands. I'm not familiar with chart.js but I have written automation against CANVAS elements. I got with dev and talked to them about what I needed access to and they gave me pointers on methods, etc. that I could call to get what I needed. I use the page object model so I ended up writing some Java functions that wrapped around the JS code that accessed the CANVAS.

Comment: I think this is probably the only way to go. In the case of chart.js, I'm not even sure it's possible to test hover text and clicks as the library doesn't appear to have any way of telling us WHERE to click/hover for a particular data element. I find it odd that a library would make its self untestable!